# which one is correct and why "I will crack a joke or I will tell a joke"

Tags: word-usage, orthography

This  morning my bro told me “*I will tell a joke*” but my sister said “*I will crack a joke.*”

I am confused. which one is right or why?

Comment: Crack a joke: *tell a joke* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/crack-a-joke

Answer (score 4):

Crack a joke is an idiom but it sort of means the same. But,it gives the impression that a joke has been made spontaneously on the spot about something.Telling a joke gives the impression of telling a forwarded joke. Slight difference but you can ignore it.

Comment: +1 for the difference.  I don’t think you should ignore it.  “Hey Joe, crack that joke you cracked the other day about the elephant “ is not something any native would say- they’d only use *tell* there.

Comment: I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Both are right. Like with many things, there is more than one way to say it.

[crack](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/crack?s=t) - 15. to utter or to tell